# C# WPF Listbox with checkboxes - Selection display

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox, selection

I'm using a Listbox with Checkboxes to select data in it. The source is an XML file like :

```
<Hosts>
  <Host Location="a">
    <IP>1.1.1.1</IP>
    <HostName>host1</HostName>
  </Host>
  <Host Location="b">
    <IP>2.2.2.2</IP>
    <HostName>host2</HostName>>
  </Host>
</Hosts>
```

The listbox is correctly displayed with checkboxes. When I select one or several entries, I can't get to retrieve the associated HostName(s). Selection is done by :

```
    private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as CheckBox;
        var item = cb.DataContext;
// a message box here shows that I have the good content (host1, host2) in item
        ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)this.MachinesList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        listBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
        MessageBox.Show(listBoxItem.ToString());
    }
```

I'm using a button to display the content :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Object selecteditem in MachinesList.SelectedItems)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(selecteditem.ToString());
    }
}
```

But the message box is printing : **System.XML.XmlElement**

I'm afraid the selection applies to the whole XML data, and not to a particular node. ie :

```
ListBoxItem listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)this.MachinesList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
```

doesn't pick the node but the complete XML element.

The Listbox is done with :

```
<!-- MACHINES LIST -->
        <!-- Grouping option for machines list -->
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource HostsData}}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@Location" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
        <!-- Display option for groups in machines list -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="categoryTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  FontWeight="Bold" Background="Gold" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- Display option for machines in machines list -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MachinesTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/> <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding XPath=HostName}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"    Margin="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

   <ListBox Name="MachinesList"
             Grid.Row="0"    Grid.Column="0"    Grid.RowSpan="2"    TextBlock.FontSize="9" Margin="2"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MachinesTemplate}"
             SelectionMode="Multiple">
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource categoryTemplate}" />
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Any help ? I'm stuck there for hours without a clue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to select the Host element, what you have right now should be working correctly but you're not providing enough detail with your MessageBoxes to see anything. It's very easy to see this by just setting a breakpoint in your event handlers but if you want to see more in the MessageBoxes you can be more specific about what to show.

Using this instead in the Checked handler you should see that the selected item is a "Host" element:

```
MessageBox.Show((listBoxItem.Content as XmlElement).Name);
```

When enumerating the selected items you can similarly examine which element it is down to whatever level of detail you need:

```
foreach (var selecteditem in MachinesList.SelectedItems.OfType<XmlElement>())
{
    MessageBox.Show(selecteditem.InnerXml);
}
```

Before you start using this for real you also need to change how you're handling the syncing of the CheckBox and ListBoxItem. At a minimum you need to also have an Unchecked handler on the CheckBox, but you can make it a lot simpler by getting rid of the event handlers and using data binding instead:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MachinesTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding XPath=HostName}" Margin="1"
                  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi John. Thank you very much. This works perfectly. The binding example you posted is indeed a lot clearer than the way I was doing. I've been searching a lot of time how to do this listbox/checkbox properly, without a concluant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are getting back an XElement because you add them to the MachinesList in the first place. But why would this be a problem? You can still select child [elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) from that XML fragment and select your hostname.